# How to auto-increment table cell items content in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

i have a problem with the universal auto-increment of the item labels in XSLT

```
<fo:table-body>
<fo:table-row>
   <fo:table-cell>
      <xsl:if test="true()">
         <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:block>$x$</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body>
               <fo:block>Volvo</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
         </fo:list-item>
      </xsl:if>
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-row>
   <fo:table-cell>
      <xsl:if test="false()">
         <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:block>$x$</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body>
               <fo:block>Opel</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
         </fo:list-item>
      </xsl:if>
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-row>
   <fo:table-cell>
      <xsl:if test="true()">
         <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:block>$x$</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body>
               <fo:block>BMW</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
         </fo:list-item>
      </xsl:if>
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-body>
```

Let's assume that every item is a separate table row. Is there any chance of using/creating an autogenerated list item labels, which indicates the actual number of items basing on the conditions met? My desired output in this situation looks like this:

```
1.Volvo 2. BMW
```

Comment: Are you hardcoding the data anyway in the XSLT? Or is the data coming from an XML input? Do you expect to compute the item number with XSLT or do you expect the XSL-FO processor with some extension to handle that? The presented markup is not clear, the start tags nest table-cell in table-row, the end tags table-row in table-cell.

Comment: Let's assume that the data is hardcoded in the XSLT, but conditions on which the presentation of the data is based is coming from the XML. I have no clear expectations about how that should work, I hoped that exists a simple solution solving the problem, which is enumerating only visible elements of the list in a generic way - without the necessity of hard-coding it with the certain numbers in "if-else" way.

Comment: Could you share the source xml , the actual used xslt and the expected outcome. Do you need besides the table , a list of some sort that depends on filtering.  If yes you could just use a separate mode that deals with that.